# Post increment - time of evaluation

Tags: c

According to my understanding, the previous value is used for evaluation of an expression when postfix operator is used.

Consider the following code

int a = 11;
int d;

case 1:d = a++ + ++a;output d has value 24

case 2:
d = a++ + a++;
output d has value 22

case 3:
    d = a + a++ + ++a;
    output d has value 34

case 4:
    d = a++ + ++a + a;
    output d has value 36

The order in which a is updated with the incremented value used for computation is inconsistent. I want to know the exact time the value is incremented during post increment.

Comment: Look up the definition of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Read the duplicate question. You can't know the exact time because it's undefined behavior.